# How do I implement COMET on Azure with Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, comet

Now that Microsoft [ported Node.JS to Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/) what is the next thing I need to do to enable COMET on this platform?

Also, is this the proper way to host a server?

```
var sys = require('util'), 
   http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.setHeader("200", {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('Hello World');
    res.end();
  }, 2000);
}).listen(8000);
sys.puts('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) module. both long polling and websocket bindings will work in Azure worker role. In web role you're restricted to long polls.

Comment: More specifically, web role runs on IIS and websockets and IIS don't go too well together yet.

Comment: @Raynos - I'm working with MSFT now.  Can you elaborate on known issues?

Comment: @makerofthings7 As far as I know the known issues are that IIS and websockets requires .NET 4.5 the last time I looked. it was merely a comment about websockets not being supported by IIS as the time of writing. I don't know what the status is now.